# Confusion about real value function and complex value function in Rudin's proof of regular Borel measure

Tags: real-analysis

In a proof of Rudin (Real and Complex Analysis), a topological space $(X, \mathcal{T})$ and a sequence of **complex** Borel measurable functions $g_n \in C_c(X) $ is given such that

1. $0 \le g_n(x) \le 1 \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{Z^+} , \forall x \in X$
2. $g_n$ functions converge pointwise to a characteristic function $\chi_v$ where $V$ is a subset of X

My question is that $g_n$ should have complex value which means $g_n(x) = a_n(x) + i \times 0 = (a_n(x),0)$ such that $a(x) \subset [0,1]$ so how can they converge pointwise to $\chi_v$ which is a real value function? Did Rudin mean $\pi_1 \circ g_n$ instead of $g_n$ ($\pi_1$ is the 1st coordinate projection map) ?[Part of the proof about regular Borel measure (Theorem 2.18 Real and Complex Analysis 3rd Edition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjHhi.jpg)

Comment: Well, of course one identifies complex numbers with zero imaginary part with real numbers. I respectfully think that you are being too formal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X$ is a set and $V \subseteq X$ is a subset, then the characteristic function of $V$ is a function from $X$ to $S$. Where $|S| = 2$. It's convenient to use $S = \{0,1\}$.

When people talk about characteristic functions, they usually mean $\iota \circ \chi_V$. Where $\iota$ is the embedding of $\{0,1\}$ into an appropriate set.

For example:

$\iota : \{0,1\} \to \mathbb R; \quad \iota(x) = \begin{cases}
1, & \text{if }x = 1 \\
0 ,& \text{if }x = 0
\end{cases}$

gives you $\iota \circ \chi_v : X \to \mathbb R$, the "real-valued" characteristic function, while
$\iota : \{0,1\} \to \mathbb C; \quad \iota(x) = \begin{cases}
1+0i, & \text{if }x = 1 \\
0+0i,& \text{if }x = 0
\end{cases}$

gives you $\iota \circ \chi_v : X \to \mathbb C$, the "complex-valued" characteristic function.

Usually the set in which $\{0,1\}$ is embedded is clear from the context and thus it's universally accepted to omit $\iota$ from $\iota \circ \chi_v$. And by the same reasoning one simply writes "characteristic function" instead of eg. "complex-valued characteristic function".